# General Debate in UN General Assembly

Tags: address

I'm looking for general debate transcripts of UN General Assembly. Recent years (2011-2016) can be found [here](http://gadebate.un.org/sessions-archive). But is there a way to get data before 2011?

I found there is a [United Nations documents search service](https://documents.un.org/prod/ods.nsf/home.xsp), but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: what have you tried? https://search.un.org/results.php?query=*transcript&lang=en&tpl=dist_search